# Reference request: Weil's uniformization theorem

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, algebraic-groups, principal-bundles, adeles

The Weil uniformization theorem says that if $k$ is an algebraically closed field, $G$ a reductive group, and $C$ a curve, we have an isomorphism of stacks $Bun_G(C)\cong G(F_C)\backslash G(\mathbb{A}_C)/G(\mathbb{O}_C)$, where $\mathbb{A}$ and $\mathbb{O}$ are the rings of adeles and integral adeles respectively. This is the version of the theorem stated in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1511.06271.pdf). However, I have seen other versions of this theorem which require e.g. that $G$ is affine, that $C$ is smooth and projective, and so on. I can't seem to find the original or definitive paper on this result, and I'm interested in generalizing it to non-algebraically-closed fields, so I would like to read that. If anyone knows either the original paper or one which describes this generalization, I would appreciate the reference.

Comment: Have you looked at Corollary 3.39 and the following discussion in the paper you cite?

Comment: I took a look at it in a bit more detail, and it does seem to prove the result over arbitrary fields. I'm still interested in finding Weil's original paper, however.